# Finding expectation and variance for multiple items when given for 1 item

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

The problem I have here is that I know this is a normal distribution question, but I don't know how to find the Variance And Mean for 50 items, they have given for 1 item

---

My book simply says :

$E(T)=50 (1.5)$

$Var(T)= 50 (0.4^2)$

---

At  first I thought they did it  by evaluating :

$E(50X)= 50 E(X)$

which seems fine, but then :

$Var(50X)= 50^2 Var(X)$

The variance  doesn't  agree with the book, so I think it must be some other thing working here. Please help, what has my book used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in noticing that $E(50X) = 50E(X)$ since $E$ is something we call a linear operation (that is: $E(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha E(X) + \beta E(Y)$).

As for $Var(50X)$, remembering that  that $Var(A) = E(A^2)-[E(A)]^2$.
$Var(50X) = E((50X)^2) - [E(50X)]^2 = E(50^2 X^2) - [50 E(X)]^2 = 50^2 (E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2) = 50^2 Var(X)$

Also remembering that standard deviation is $\sigma$ and variance is $\sigma^2$, that is standard deviation is the sqrt of the variance.

so, if $\sigma_X = .4$, then $Var(X) = .4^2$, and we have $\sigma_{50X} = \sqrt(Var(50X) = \sqrt(50^2 Var(X)) = 50(.4^2)$.

If your book stated that $\sigma_T = 50(.4^2)$ then the book was correct.  If it stated that $Var(T) = 50(.4^2)$ then it was likely a typo meant to write $\sigma$ instead.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I am correct :)